# DRF TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type CustomUser)

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I want to add a field to a serializer that counts all occurrences of a word (a tag).

the 2 relevant models in Models.py are:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name or ''


class Tagging(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    gameround = models.ForeignKey(Gameround, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    resource = models.ForeignKey(Resource, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='taggings')
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    # media_type = models.ForeignKey(Gamemode, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    origin = models.URLField(max_length=256, blank=True, default='')

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.tag) or ''

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()

        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True, blank=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, default=timezone.now)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_uploader = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def get_username(self):
        return self.username

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.email} ({self.username})' or ''
```

The Serializer I am trying to write is:

```
class TagCountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  tag = TagSerializer(read_only=True)
  tag_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_tag_count')

  class Meta:
    model = Tagging
    fields = ('id', 'tag', 'gameround', 'resource', 'tag_count')

  def get_tag_count(self, obj):
    # return obj.tag.all().count()
    tag_count = Tagging.objects.filter(tag=obj.tag).count()
    return tag_count

  def to_representation(self, data):
    data = super().to_representation(data)
    
    return data
```

I have tried a couple of potential solutions for the get_tag_count() method, including the ones visible here but I keep getting this error "Cannot query "tag name": Must be "Tag" instance."
Does anyone know how I can get around this?

Comment: Share the full error traceback

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use the `.tag` of the object, so:

```
def get_tag_count(self, obj):
    # return obj.tag.all().count()
    tag_count = Tagging.objects.filter(tag=obj.tag).count()
    return tag_count
```

This will return the number of `Tagging` objects that refer to the `tag` you are serializing.

Comment: I did and I get TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type CustomUser)

Comment: @CarinaTheBookworm: this is likely not due to the serializer, likely something is wron in your `CustomUser` model. Can you share that model and the full traceback? Please *edit* the question.

Comment: I updated it now. It also says "Error during template rendering"

Comment: @CarinaTheBookworm: yes, but the problem is in your `CustomUser` model. Can you please share this in the question?

Comment: I have added it now.

Comment: @CarinaTheBookworm: is there any model where you return `self.user` in the `__str__` method?

Comment: Only in the gameround model.

Comment: @CarinaTheBookworm: can you share the `Gameround` model as well. Likely the problem is located there.

Comment: Ok, I removed it and it works! Thank you so much!